# My page goes blank when I call Router from "react-router-dom". What did I do wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is the App.js file I run

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
  


export default App;
```

I keep getting a blank file, but It displays if I comment out the Router

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? From your project directory you can check by running `npm list react-router-dom`. I don't see any issue with the code if you have `react-router-dom@5` installed.

Comment: react-router-dom@6.2.2 is the version I installed

Comment: It looks like you're importing "Router" twice, because you are renaming "BrowserRouter" to "Router". Try removing "as Router".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` you should wrap the `Route` components in a required `Routes` component that handles the route path matching and rendering. The `Route` component API also changed a bit, there is now only a single `element` prop that takes a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, to render the routed content.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

For a more complete guide of the differences between RRD v5 and v6 check the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5).

OFC, if you want to keep your existing code you *could* revert back to `react-router-dom@5`.

- `npm uninstall -s react-router-dom`
- `npm install -s react-router-dom@5`